# Cannot start Homebrew Mysql on OSX - ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/MY-MBP.fios-router.home.pid)

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I read several posts here about this very issue. I tried several things including this:

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=whoami --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

and none have worked. How do I un-hose Mysql on OSX? And why is it pointed to some nonexistent pid file that is associated with my fios router?